# fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, c++, netbeans, java-native-interface

I want to learn that how we can call a java function from C++,after following some links i came to know that we need to add following header file in C++ file

```
#include <jni.h>
```

but when I added this file in C++ file in **Netbeans IDE** I got following error

```
fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
```

How can this error be removed, I am just beginner in JNI.

I went through previous questions asked at stackoverflow but was not able to go through the Problem.

Here is my comile output:

```
"/C/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/bin./make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Simer/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JniDemo'
"/C/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/bin./make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/jnidemo.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Simer/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JniDemo'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:9:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Simer/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JniDemo'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Simer/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JniDemo'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are compiling with MinGW without including Java headers, thats why it complains about not found

Try to add this option to your compilation command `-I"c:/path/to/jdk/include" -I"c:/path/to/jdk/include/win32" -D__int64="long long"`.

The last option is to avoid the error caused because windows compiler uses the type __int64 and gcc uses long long.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Netbeans JNI tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/beginning-jni-linux.html)?

It goes through everything you should need to do in pretty good detail.